# I want to change the key of multidimensional array

Tags: php

I want to change the key of the multidimensional array. the array contains key like 1,15,23,45 which should be replaced by normal index key like 0,1,2,3. I tried with below code. Something is missing in below code. Please, anyone, suggest to me.

```
$keys = array_keys($data);
$d = 0;
foreach($data as $row){
    $key_data[$d] = $data[$keys[$d]];
    unset($row[$keys[$d]]);
    $d++;
}
```

**Current Output**

Array
(

```
[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [app_dealer_id] => 15
                [dealer_name] => Sharad Thombre
                [shopname] => Shivshankar Fertilizer
                [contact_num] => 9049121143
                [district] => Parbhani
            )

    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [app_dealer_id] => 18
                [dealer_name] => Gajanan Khapre
                [shopname] => Shreyas Krishi Kendra
                [contact_num] => 8007791946
                [district] => Parbhani
            )

    )

)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Array
    (

        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [app_dealer_id] => 15
                        [dealer_name] => Sharad Thombre
                        [shopname] => Shivshankar Fertilizer
                        [contact_num] => 9049121143
                        [district] => Parbhani
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [app_dealer_id] => 18
                        [dealer_name] => Gajanan Khapre
                        [shopname] => Shreyas Krishi Kendra
                        [contact_num] => 8007791946
                        [district] => Parbhani
                    )

            )
)
```

Comment: http://php.net/array_values will reset the indices.

Comment: ^ put in on the end of the loop block

Answer (score 3):

use [array_values()](http://php.net/array_values)

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/cUAdl

Answer (score 0):

From php.net :
**[array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)()** returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.

So just add it after your loop to reindex you array :

```
$keys = array_keys($data);
$d = 0;
foreach($data as $row){
    $key_data[$d] = $data[$keys[$d]];
    unset($row[$keys[$d]]);
    $d++;
}
$newArray = array_keys($key_data);
```